# Speeding up an optimization involving matrix products in CVXR

Tags: r, convex, constrained-optimization

I have an optimization problem where I need to minimize
$$-\log \det(U^T \text{diag}(p) U + V^T\text{diag}(1 - p)V)$$
where $p$ is a vector of probabilities, i.e. $0 \leq p_i \leq 1$, and $U$ and $V$ are two predetermined matrices. I also have a monotonicity constraint that the vector $p$ must be nondecreasing in its index, i.e. $p_1 \leq p_2 \leq ... \leq p_n$.

In CVXR, I code this as

```
#A %*% p >= 0 encodes the monotonicity constraint
A = diag(1, nrow = n)
for (i in 2:n)
{
  A[i, i - 1] = -1
}

p = Variable(n)
objective = -1 * log_det(t(U) %*% diag(p) %*% U + t(V) %*% diag(1 - p) %*% V)
mon_constraints = list(p <= 1, A %*% p >= 0)
prob = Problem(Minimize(objective), mon_constraints) 
solution = solve(prob)
p_opt = solution$getValue(p)
```

This runs fine with just the base constraint $0 \leq p \leq 1$, but adding the monotonicity constraint makes it quite slow. I am wondering if there is a way to make this more efficient. One idea I had was to store each of the matrices $u_i u_i^T$ and $v_iv_i^T$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ ahead of time so we only need to compute them once, then change the argument of log_det to
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} p_i u_i u_i^T + (1 - p_i) v_i v_i^T$$
I do this as follows

```
Ulist = list()
Vlist = list()
for (i in 1:n)
{
  Ulist[[i]] = U[i,] %*% t(U[i,])
  Vlist[[i]] = V[i,] %*% t(V[i,])
}

f = function(p)
{
  puu = Map('*', p, Ulist) 
  pvv = Map('*', 1 - p, Vlist)
  finalmat = Reduce('+', puu) + Reduce('+', pvv)
  return(finalmat) 
}

p = Variable(n)
objective = -1 * log_det(f(p))
mon_constraints = list(p <= 1, A %*% p >= 0)
prob = Problem(Minimize(objective), mon_constraints) 
solution = solve(prob)
p_opt = solution$getValue(p)
```

But when I try this, I get an error when defining the objective function: " Error in dots[[1L]][[1L]] : this S4 class is not subsettable." I assume this has to do with me supplying my own function using lists, which is incompatible with CVXR somehow.

I am not very familiar with CVX and would appreciate if anyone had any pointers or suggestions to speed up the optimization at all.

Comment: I would not try to do this with constraints, but instead would parameterize the variables to require no constraints.  There are many ways; you might have to experiment.  As an example, you could take $p_i = (\exp(x_1)+\exp(x_2)+\cdots+\exp(x_i)) / (\exp(x_1)+\exp(x_2) + \cdots + \exp(x_n) +1)$ and no constraints on the $x_i.$ You can simplify the objective function, too, to reduce the number of matrix multiplications down to a $O(n^2)$ operation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I'm a bit confused about two things: (1) the transformation you outline is nonconvex, so I don't see how CVX could accommodate that (2) how can $U^TDU$ be computed in O(n^2) operations? It equals $\sum p_i u_i u_i^T$, which seems to me to be $O(n^3)$ operations ($n^2$ for each $p_i u_i u_i^T$ term, times $n$ such terms).

Comment: (2) Linear algebra helps: premultiply the expression by $U^{\prime-1}$ and postmultiply it by $V^{-1},$ thereby reducing the formula to the sum of two products, each of which multiplies a matrix by a *diagonal* matrix: that's $O(n^2).$  (1) The loss of convexity might mean you cannot apply CVX, but is this an exercise in using that particular software solution or is it an exercise in solving a statistical problem?  If it's the latter, you should not be concerned about using other software solutions.

Comment: Have you timed your code using the built-in atom `diff`? Your constraint would just be ```
diff(p) >= 0
```
It would also help if you posted a full example.